# if py file exists in /root

Tags: php, python, ubuntu

So I put a python code in my root folder called test.py.  I tried to see if it exists in PHP by running this

```
$file ='/root/test.py';
echo file_exists($file);
```

The file does in-fact exist, but the echo is always false.

Comment: im reasonably sure www-data (or whatever user is running the php webserver) would not have permission to access /root folder .... you need to look into linux and permissions ....  ... /root is probably not an appropriate place to store whatever this is

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to relay on /root folder to exec scripts. Add the fact a PY script called by php!!!!

My tip is to study better [the files permissions on linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions)

I suggest create a folder inside your PHP project folder (can call scripts) and run the py script inside it, checking the permission of the folder, if folder exists and that stuff.

The perfect case is: never relay your project into a system structure, it's too risky and too dependable.